# HDMI to Component Conversion

Tags: hdmi, drm, crt, hdcp

Im not sure if this is the best place to post a question like this, but I am not sure where else too.

I am trying to play a BluRay on an older CRT projector. The highest quality input on the projector is a (RGB) Component Connection. The player I need to connect only has a HDMI output. If I were to use a HDMI to Component converter box could it work? I ask because I am worried that DRM and HDCP content protection will complain I am converting the signal to Analog.

Also if it would work better I have the option of using a Xbox One to play the BluRay.

Thank You

Comment: Perhaps http://video.stackexchange.com/ would be better?

Comment: Exactly what make & model of CRT PJ are you using?  Most industrial/professional PJs (that are capable of resolutions better than NTSC or PAL) typically have RGBHV inputs (that are compatible with VGA) (using BNC connectors) rather than component video inputs (which typically use RCA connectors).  BTW component video is not RGB; it's YPbPr.